# RestKit Error: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'No route found named

Tags: ios, routes, restkit

I am using RestKit and the above error comes up. However, it appears that only one specific route cannot be found, for all other routes it is perfectly working. If I replace the route name to some other route I implemented, it works.
And I am sure the route is declared properly, as I copy/pasted from other routes.

The route is named "makeShout". When I try to use it, the above error occurs. Interestingly, if I change the route name in the route declaration statement, the error message changes to "Invalid parameter not satisfying: route". This means, that the first error "no route found" cannot be true, since renaming the route leads to a different error message, which proves that before the route was actually found.

My declaration is:

```
[gocoffeeObjectManager.router.routeSet 
 addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithName:@"makeShout"
                     pathPattern:@"/gocoffee/api/V1/shout/:eventType/:eventTime/:locationLat/:locationLng/:radius/:targetGender/:buddyOnly"
                          method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];
```

And I use it as follows:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager]
 enqueueObjectRequestOperation:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] requestWithPathForRouteNamed:@"makeShout" object:obj parameters:nil] success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
    NSLog(@"jo");
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);}]];
```

Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: Is this route used at some different time than others? Did you debug?

Comment: No, I use the route at the same place as some others. Debugging just gives me the information above: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'No route found named 'makeShout''. Really strange....  Thank you!!

Comment: I'd say you should debug and drill in to see which routes are registered after you think it should be and when you try to use it

Comment: Hey I just found the error...one of the object propoerties was an NSDate. Restkit does not seem to be able to deal with it, so I changed to UNIX epoch timestamp...now its working like a charm... so the error message was indeed misleading... thanks anyway for your help... michael